# Adding fonts to a container gives it a weird border

Tags: css, layout, fonts

I would like to specify a font to be used everywhere on my website unless overriden.. I tried going about that this way: `body {font-family: Poppins;}`.

What I experienced with this approach is that fonts have different.. for lack of better understanding - margins? For instance, compared to the default Arial, the font Poppins expands all my containers by 2 pixels. This [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w2rd2m0y/130/) tries  to demonstrate some peculiarities that I do not understand. What I want to ask with this question is an explanation of the behaviour of this code.

My objectives is to define a font to all elements of a container (body e.g.) without changing any layout. Please ask about anything I may have been unclear about!

```css
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:500|Poppins);

body {
  font-family: Poppins;
}

a:first-child {
  background: green;
  font-family:Poppins;
}

a:last-child {
  background: red;
  font-family: Oswald;
}

.div {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  background: blue;
}

.div:nth-of-type(3) a {
  font-family: Poppins;
}

.div:nth-of-type(4) {
  font-family: Oswald;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <a>33px</a>
  <a>36px</a>
  38px
</div>

<br>

<div class="div">
  <a>Oswald 36px</a>
  Poppins 38px
</div>

<br>

<div class="div">
  <a>Poppins 33px</a>
  Poppins 35px
</div>

<br>

<div class="div">
  <a>Oswald 36px</a>
  Oswald 36px
</div>
```

**EDIT:**
Attaching screenshot in case anything is OS specific. The fiddle renders as a blue box on my windows machine with the same version of Chrome..

[image]

Comment: That's custom font for you, it has different height and spacing. Maybe if you know someone who knows how to make fonts, maybe you can edit the font to make it better

Comment: @Huangism I fully expect fonts to have different heights and spacing. But I don't understand how 'different height' accounts for situation seen in the 3rd div where the container is bigger than its containing text element.

Comment: You will have to edit and look at the font itself, it probably have some kind of build in margin. You can fix this with by changing the line height but on a large scale, this will get very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Different fonts have different character widths, line-heights, and letter spacing. That change is normal. You'll have to specify in your CSS what letter-spacing or line-height to use to make it closer to that of Arial's if it's a problem. Be aware that these rules cascade.

Comment: I have edited the question to include a screenshot. If it is the same as you see, I fail to see the significance of letter spacing or line height for that matter.

Comment: Oh, I see! That's line-height. I'll add it to my answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems your problem isn't exactly font-related. You don't like the weird space the unfloated inline elements are making. Set them to float and the space goes away:

```css
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:500|Poppins);

body {
  font-family: Poppins;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

a {
   float: left;
}

a:first-child {
  background: green;
  font-family:Poppins;
}

a:last-child {
  background: red;
  font-family: Oswald;
}

div {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  background: blue;
}

div:nth-of-type(3) a {
  font-family: Poppins;
}

#osw {
  font-family: Oswald;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a>33px</a>
  <a>36px</a>
  38px
</div>

<br>

<div>
  <a>Oswald 36px</a>
  Poppins 38px
</div>

<br>

<div>
  <a>Poppins 33px</a>
  Poppins 35px
</div>

<br>

<div id="osw">
  <a>Oswald 36px</a>
  Oswald 36px
</div>
```

```css
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:500|Poppins);

body {
  font-family: Poppins;
}

a:first-child {
  background: green;
  font-family:Poppins;
}

a:last-child {
  background: red;
  font-family: Oswald;
}

div {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  background: blue;
}

div:nth-of-type(3) a {
  font-family: Poppins;
}

#osw {
  font-family: Oswald;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a>33px</a>
  <a>36px</a>
  38px
</div>

<br>

<div>
  <a>Oswald 36px</a>
  Poppins 38px
</div>

<br>

<div>
  <a>Poppins 33px</a>
  Poppins 35px
</div>

<br>

<div id="osw">
  <a>Oswald 36px</a>
  Oswald 36px
</div>
```

Comment: As my original fiddle did not work on my windows machine, for some reason, neither does these example. Also it is very much font related in that my question is WHY this happens when I change font.